# CLion Vulkan quick documentation access?

Tags: documentation, vulkan

I know that CLion supports documentation done with Doxygen and that with CTRL+Q I can view it.

Is it possible to have the same working with Vulkan ?
Is there a version of the headers that have compatible comment in them or any other system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no version of the headers with documentation. That was discussed internally, but with something as complex as Vulkan the header documentation would become pretty verbose and hard to maintain.

Comment: I've been thinking it would be nice to at least have a Chrome extension that would intercept URLs to the full vulkan spec with some anchor half-way through and re-write them to URLs into the chunked version of the spec, so that I don't kill a browser tab every time I try to follow a doc link.

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer. @jherico I agree that an extension for the ide or the browser would be nice. I'm fine if a shortcut would just open a page on my browser or internally in my ide